# "movie" and articles

Tags: word-choice, difference, articles

What are the differences between the four sentences below?

1. I'm interested in Japanese movies.
2. I'm interested in the Japanese movies.
3. I'm interested in a Japanese movie.
4. I'm interested in the Japanese movie.

I often hear the expression "Let's go to the movies."  Here, "movies" is plural though you are going to see only one movie. So, I'm not sure about the articles around it.

Comment: Going "to the movies" is an English idiom and has nothing to do with your examples. In your examples, the definite and indefinite articles have their usual meanings.

Comment: Yes, what @MarcInManhattan said, and plural works the normal way in your examples too

Comment: Shouldn't it be "What are the differences between the four sentences below?"? I think "the movies" refers to the theatre/cinema/place and that it means "Let's go to the theatre" in a rather excited tone, imagining a world of movies.